# Is my avocado plant looking healthy?

Tags: houseplants, avocado

[image: Avocado Plant]

I'm sorry if this is another one of those useless-for-the-community post but I'm just curious, if anyone could tell me if my avocado plant is looking healthy or not. Perhaps if you're an expert and can tell me what variety of avocado this is so I can keep an eye out for its nutrient needs.
(PS, some of the leaves seem to be curling down, is that a problem I can solve quickly?)

Comment: give this plant more light! It grows outside in the tropics and is considered a tree.  It needs a lot of light or will end up looking very spindly

Answer (score 4):

Your avocado looks fairly healthy...good soil, color is a bit on the light green side and curling down could be due to time of day or temperature.

The big question is fertilizer.  Have you used a balanced fertilizer?  N P K plus micro nutrients?  How old is your plant?

Sure looks like it is lacking in chemicals for photosynthesis.  Fertilizer.  Let us know what you've added, not added for chemistry so this plant is able to make its own 'food'.  My go to fertilizer if you've never added any fertilizer to this pot is OSMOCOTE 14-14-14.  Extended release.  Timed release and for your avocado just half the amount will make a huge difference.  Less is better than too much none is a slow death.